# Angular4-Bootstrap4: Create subnav bar from navbar

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm trying to implement two layers of navbar, and second one becomes visible with its respective options on clicking a link in first nav bar.

I tried to implement it with `id` and `data-target` as explained in its [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navbar/#external-content), but plugin doesn't seem to work and [ngx-bootstrap](http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/index-bs4.html#/) has not yet developed module for navbar.

HTML

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarLevelOne">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarLevelOne">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#a">A</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#b">B</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#c">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="a" >
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">a</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">b</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">c</a></li>        
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="b" >
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">p</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">q</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">r</a></li>        
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="c" >
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">x</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">y</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">z</a></li>        
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your section where you have your subnav. Try to move the three nav lists into their own "collapse div". Like so:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
      <div class="collapse" id="a" *ngIf="a">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">a</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">b</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">c</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="b" *ngIf="b">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">p</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">q</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">r</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse" id="c" *ngIf="c">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">x</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">y</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">z</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

When you click on a button that triggers the collapse function it only triggers the specified section. Therefore, if you show section A, and then click to show section B, A will still be there. To solve this, put in "*ngIf" on each section (like I've done above), the section A will then only be visible if a is set and same for C and B.

To make this work, make a simple function in your app.component.ts class:

```
setNav(s: string) {
    this.a = false;
    this.b = false;
    this.c = false;

    switch (s) {
      case 'a':
        this.a = true;
        break;
      case 'b':
        this.b = true;
        break;
      case 'c':
        this.c = true;
        break;
    }
  }
```

and then have click events on each of the buttons on the main nav:

```
<li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#a" (click)="setNav('a')">A</a></li>
```

The full HTML is then:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse bg-inverse">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarLevelOne">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">BRAND</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarLevelOne">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#a" (click)="setNav('a')">A</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#b" (click)="setNav('b')">B</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" routerLinkActive="active"  data-target="#c" (click)="setNav('c')">C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="collapse" id="a" *ngIf="a">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">a</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">b</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="b" *ngIf="b">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">p</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">q</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">r</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="collapse" id="c" *ngIf="c">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">x</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">y</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">z</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Hope it solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks for this approach, but I have kept this as the last option. I was looking for data-target and id approach, so that we wont have to set values in component. Wanted to check if I was missing something.